# Comment peut-on déchiffrer « Bi1 » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, jeux-de-mots

C'est quoi « bi1 » ? Pouvez-vous me l'expliquer, s'il vous plait ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

It is a way of writing *bien*, especially on texting, where the "en" ending, pronounced here exactly like "in" (/ɛ̃/) is replaced by the number "1" (*un*) which used to be pronounced /œ̃/ but has merged with /ɛ̃/ in roughly the northern half of France.

You might read the following SMS on your phone:

> **[jspr k tu va bi1](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/jspr)**

That means *J'espère que tu vas bien* (I hope you are doing well.)

[A supermarket chain](https://www.bi1.fr/mieux-nous-connaitre/chiffres-cles/) even chose it as its name:

[image]